# Magento : Custom Options fields position

Tags: php, magento, themes, magento-1.7

Can you help me how can I change the position of Custom Options on product page. I mean: First **product-options** fields are displayed, then **add_to_cart** fields. I'm Very appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the position of the custom options then the right place for you to look is in

> app/diesign/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

First you should copy this file to you theme and edit there(Is the good practice in magento).

In this file search for the code snippet as below.

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

In this reference handle you will see the blocks

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

Place these two blocks below the blocks which renders the custom options block i.e.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
```

This should do the trick.

Hope this will help.